# Qt Creator is running in fullscreen

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a weird issue with QT Creator. The soft is opening in full screen.
It is annoying because I don't have the bar with File, Edit, Tools etc...

How to disable this fullscreen mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch between fullscreen and window mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Still, it's strange that the menus aren't visible, normally they are retained even in full screen mode.